# EF version updated to 3.1.22 from 2.1 breaks Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, upgrade, asp.net-core-3.1

I am upgrading my ASP.NET Core Web API project from .NET Core 2.1 to 3.1. I also needed to upgrade EF Core from 2.1 to 3.1.

After upgrading EF, the Linq queries which were working in .NET Core 2.1 are not working (might be backward compatibility not supported with new version or change in using Linq).

What are standard ways to rewrite linq queries to make it functional? Which things in linq changed from 2.1 to 3.1? The Issue is related to select clause having operation related to ANY() etc.

```
    var classes =
        (
            from z in Context.aaa.Where(x => x.Id == Id)
            join b in Context.bbb on z.Id equals b.Id
            join bc in Context.ccc.Where(x => x.IsActive == true) on b.Id equals bc.Id
            join fcc in Context.ddd.Where(x => x.IsActive == true) on bc.Id equals fcc.Id
            join fc in Context.eee.Where(x => x.IsActive == true )
                .Include(i => i.Level) on fcc.Id equals fc.Id
            select new
            {
                bc.IsUserRequired,
                IsHiddenByOverrideOrExclusion = zoneList.Any(x => x.Id == fc.Id && x.IsHidden == true) || (!zoneList.Any(x => x.Id == fc.Id && x.IsHidden == false) && functioncheckFlag(fc, Id, category)),
            }
        ).Distinct().AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: Probably it cannot convert `functioncheckFlag` to the SQL. EF Core 2.x silently evaluated everything on the client side if something cannot be converted to the SQL, which is really bad for performance. If you remove `Distinct` it may work.

Comment: Nothing in LINQ library should of changed when upgrading.  The issue is the connection to the database (Dbcontext) failing.  One common reason for failing is code may be using  HTTPS (secure) instead of HTTP (not secure).  HTTPS uses TLS and there are lots of reasons TLS fails.

Comment: @jdweng, probably you have not read [Breaking changes list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes) it's huge between 2.x and 3.0 and first one is current issue.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv : I have read the breaking changes for ALL versions of CORE.  I made my response looking at the code posted.  The are no breaking changes for LINQ.  The OP is using ENTITY (Context) and the most likely reason for Entity breaking is the actual HTTP connection.

Comment: @jdweng, I see `functioncheckFlag` - it is definitely not convertible to the SQL. 
 `zoneList.Any` also will fail if it is local collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF Core 3.x have changed translation behavior. EF Core no longer silently process data on the client side. So translation will fail because `functioncheckFlag` cannot be converted to the SQL and, probably, `zoneList.Any` also if `zoneList` is local collection.

To solve problem, you have to do `Distinct` on the client side.

```cs
var classes =
    (
        from z in Context.aaa.Where(x => x.Id == Id)
        join b in Context.bbb on z.Id equals b.Id
        join bc in Context.ccc.Where(x => x.IsActive == true) on b.Id equals bc.Id
        join fcc in Context.ddd.Where(x => x.IsActive == true) on bc.Id equals fcc.Id
        join fc in Context.eee.Where(x => x.IsActive == true ) on fcc.Id equals fc.Id
        select new
        {
            bc.IsUserRequired,
            IsHiddenByOverrideOrExclusion = zoneList.Any(x => x.Id == fc.Id && x.IsHidden == true) || (!zoneList.Any(x => x.Id == fc.Id && x.IsHidden == false) && functioncheckFlag(fc, Id, category)),
        }
    )
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Distinct();
```

Also removed `Include`, it is not needed if you have `Select` at the end of the query.

Comment: thanks for response it help me alot. So I have split the linq query into two ,first will pull up data with joins and second will customize select parameters.

Comment: Actually it is not problem for EF to process last `Select`, but `Distinct` means that everything inside `Select` should be convertible to the SQL